# How to properly say "I put quality before evetything else" (slogan)?

Tags: phrase-usage

I am writing a resume and I want to say that I put quality before everything else. It should show that I can negotiate about anything, but I stick to quality standards I set ahead even if it will break business relations.

Can I say "quality beyond anything"? I'd like it be short, like a slogan.

Can you propose anything else which is good to be put in the resume?

Comment: "Quality beyond anything" I understand what that means, but it doesn't sound very correct. Beyond means Farther than, which doesn't really make sense in this context. "Above" in this context means "to a greater degree or extent than (something)", so you are saying "The importance on quality is to a greater degree then anything else". Also, saying "quality above anything" sounds like "Quality above any one particular thing". It would make more sense to say "Quality above everything"

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to say that. A few being listed here...

> To me, (the) quality is of paramount importance 
>  Quality first *(as you asked a slogan)* 
>  I don't compromise anything over quality

And so on...

Actually, this is opinion base I guess.

Comment: What about Quality above everything? You can understand the meaning?

Comment: It's clumsy, don't use it. The commonest I've read/practiced is: Quality First

Comment: +1 for the slogan and 'of paramount importance', -1 for "compromise anything over quality".  You don't "compromise *on* quality".

Comment: @TRomano Really? I won't mind using [that way](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=kYHmBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=%22compromise+over+quality%22&source=bl&ots=5TocS3GJIP&sig=5owINBIS3VwGt6zrEqJh7Irnlu4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0RgEVef3NYGdugSZ-oDYBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22compromise%20over%20quality%22&f=false) though!

Comment: @Maulik V. Check out the names of the authors of the text you cited.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(compromise+on)%2C(compromise+over)&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28compromise%20on%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28compromise%20over%29%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend, My philosophy is "Quality First". Or, depending on exactly who you think will be reading the resume, you might use "motto" rather than "philosophy", as motto is less pretentious than philosophy.